# In a Hopf algebra, the antipode $S$ satisfies $S(1)=1$...?

Tags: abstract-algebra

So, if our antipode $S \in \operatorname{End}(H)$ satisfies $S(1)=1$, doesn't that mean that $S=\operatorname{Id}_H?$ I mean, $S$ is a linear map, so wouldn't it be completely described by the value it takes on $1$?

Comment: Is $H$ is a Hopf algebra over the ring $R$, then $S$ is $R$-linear, but not necessarily $H$-linear.

Comment: Hmmm in the text i'm reading Hopf algebras are always over vector spaces. So is the point that $S(1)=1$ means that $S$ fixes the basis vectors, but not the values from the field?

Comment: $S(1)=1$ means $S(1)=1$. Here $1$ is the multiplicative unit of the algebra $H$.

Comment: Right. Man Algebras are pretty abstract things really... I want to think of $1$ as being attached to a single distinguished basis vector but it need not be

Comment: Does $S(1)=1$ have any immediate corollaries I should be aware of?